# database management to goods to store their categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a web site witch contain goods. these goods have their own categories.for a
example a good can be categorized in many categories or sub categories.
I already have a item table witch contain their properties. and can anyone say how to keep it`s categories in database without duplicating data

Comment: Read this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

Ok. In this case an Item may have many categories and a category may have many Items. So its a many to many relationship. Try as follows,

Your Item table may look like this,

`Item(id, description, amount, ... )`

In your Category table,

`Category(id, name, description, ... )`

And there will be another table to assign categories to items,

`ItemCategoryAssignments(itemId, categoryId)`

And there will be two foreign keys at ItemCategoryAssignments table. That,

`itemId references id in the Item tabel`

and

`categoryId references id in the Category tabel`

Like that. There will be no duplicated rows. Hope this will help.